# Groovy Project Setting in IDEA IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, jenkins, groovy

I'm using IDEA to write groovy scripts for my jenkins job.  So I have these imports

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
import hudson.FilePath
import hudson.model.Node
import hudson.model.Slave
import jenkins.model.Jenkins
```

Before I added `jenkins-core-2.9.jar` into the project dependency, those jenkins classes are marked in red.  Then I added the jar as a dependency by "File"->"Project Structure"->"Modules"->"Dependencies"[image]

Then those red marks are gone.  However, when I tried to run the script, it says `Error:(14, 1) Groovyc: unable to resolve class jenkins.model.Jenkins`.  What else do I need to do?

Comment: Are you running the script from the command line?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it was a permission issue. For me this command fixed it: `sudo chmod o=r jenkins-core-2.73.3.jar`

Answer (score -1):

As stated in [this link](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/synchronizing-changes-in-gradle-project-and-intellij-idea-project.html),

> Note that if you configure a dependency through the Project Structure dialog, the dependency will only appear in the IntelliJ IDEA Project tool window, not in the Gradle tool window.

Adding the dependency like this only adds the dependency in the idea workspace. When you run the task either from the gradle tool window, or from an external command line tool, that dependency no longer exists. You should add it to your gradle dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile "org.jenkins-ci.main:jenkins-core:2.9"
}
```

You can configure a repository to load this dependency from. This repository can be a file path, or a maven repository etc.

See [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html) for more details on gradle dependency management.